# How to distribute a row into different row grouped by the value it has and date created?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table consisting of `result`, `name` and `created_at` like :

```
id | name | result | created_at
1  | Sam  |   1    | 2018-07-12 05:08:04
2  | Tam  |   1    | 2018-07-12 06:08:04
3  | Qam  |   0    | 2018-07-12 07:08:04
4  | Yam  |   1    | 2018-09-12 04:08:04
5  | Xam  |   0    | 2018-09-12 06:08:04
6  | Lam  |   0    | 2018-11-12 07:08:04
```

(the 1 represents pass where as 0 represent fails) I want to group the data by created at date which displays the count of result success or failed in seperate colums like:

```
 fail | pass   | created_at
  0   |   2    | 2018-07-12 05:08:04
  1   |   1    | 2018-09-12 04:08:04
  1   |   0    | 2018-11-12 07:08:04
```

I could count the value of just pass or fail with this query: `select count(result) from call_history where result = 1 GROUP BY DATE(created_at)`, but wasn't able to provide double where clause for different rows.

Comment: You can use *conditional aggregation*. If you search for these terms you can find plenty of examples here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to return a non-null result only for successes/failures, and then use `count`, which skips `null`s:

```
SELECT   COUNT(CASE result WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS fail,
         COUNT(CASE result WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS pass,
         created_at
FROM     call_history
GROUP BY created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT SUM(1 - result) as fail,
       SUM(result as pass)
       created_at
FROM call_history
GROUP BY created_at;
```